# Checkbox: передача двух значений

Tags: html, php

А кто подскажет. 
Как мне передавать через чекбокс не только on но и off если он не выбран+)

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="chek">
```

Comment: @RattleSneyk

    <label><input type="radio" name="switch" value="on" checked="checked" />On</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="switch" value="off" />Off</label>

http://jsfiddle.net/FK4Z9/

Comment: эм. Это не чекбокс=)

Comment: @RattleSneyk потому что выключенный чекбокс при сабмите формы не воспринимается. Разве что через js перехватывать сабмит и засовывать туда данные руками.

Comment: Да уже все. Решил проблему.=)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="chek" value="off">
<input type="checkbox" name="chek">
```

Если включен чекбокс - передаст on, если нет - off

Comment: Если включен чекбокс - передаст "off,on"

Comment: Array
(
    [chek] => off
)

Comment: Array
(
    [chek] => on
) - это при включенном чекбоксе. Два ответа может быть в массиве, но тогда имя должно быть check[]

Answer (score 0):

Только через скрипт.
Для проверки предыдущего состояния добавил кастомное поле `last`.

```js
~function () {
  var chk = document.getElementById('chk')
  chk.last = chk.indeterminate = true
  
  chk.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (this.checked && !chk.last) {
      chk.last = this.indeterminate = true
      this.checked = false
    } else {
      chk.last = false
    }
  })
  
  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    document.getElementById('res').value = this.indeterminate ? '' : chk.checked
  })
}()
```

```css
label { display: block; }
input + span::before { content: "unchecked"; color: red; }
input:checked + span::before { content: "checked"; color: green; }
input:indeterminate + span::before { content: "indeterminate"; color: silver; }
```

```html
<form>
  <label><input id=chk type=checkbox><span></span></label>
  <input type=hidden id=res name=chk>
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```